# Update query not working due to page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-update, pageload

Currently am working in a project where user page will load in page load, am updating the user details , the update data is not reflecting in my database , the page is loading again with old data..

Here is my code:

```
public partial class userprofile : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        }

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string strquery = "select * from insertuser Where companyname='Prhemnath'";
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
        cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdd.CommandText = strquery;
        cmdd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtcompanyname.Text = sdr["companyname"].ToString();
                ddtypeofcmpy.SelectedValue = sdr["typeofcompany"].ToString();
                txtauthname.Text = sdr["authorizedperson"].ToString();
                txtauthdesg.Text = sdr["authorizedperdesig"].ToString();
                txtregoffice.Text = sdr["registeredoffaddress"].ToString();
                txtcorroffice.Text = sdr["correspondanceaddress"].ToString();
                txtll1.Text = sdr["landline1"].ToString();
                txtll2.Text = sdr["landline2"].ToString();
                txtmob1.Text = sdr["mobile1"].ToString();
                txtmob2.Text = sdr["mobile2"].ToString();
                txtfax.Text = sdr["email"].ToString();
                txtemail.Text = sdr["email"].ToString();
                txtweb.Text = sdr["website"].ToString();
                txtusername.Text = sdr["username"].ToString();
                txtnumempcp.Text = sdr["empwithcp"].ToString();
                txtnonumempcp.Text = sdr["empwocp"].ToString();
                txtchnpan.Text = sdr["newCHAPAN"].ToString();
                txtchalicence.Text = sdr["newCHAlicence"].ToString();
                txtchptreg.Text = sdr["CHPTregnumber"].ToString();
                txtchptvalid.Text = sdr["CHPTvalidity"].ToString();
                chkaurangabad.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["aurangabad"]);
                chkbangalore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bangalore"]);
                chkchn.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["chennai"]);
                chklcochin.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["cochin"]);
                chkdelhi.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["delhi"]);
                chkgoa.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["goa"]);
                chkhyd.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["hyderabad"]);
                chkindore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["kakinada"]);
                chkkandla.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["kolkatta"]);
                chkludhiana.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["ludhiana"]);
                chkmangalore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["mangalore"]);
                chkmumbai.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bombay"]);
                chknagpur.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["nagpur"]);
                chknashik.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["nashik"]);
                chkpatna.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["patna"]);
                chkpune.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["pune"]);
                chkrajasthan.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["rajasthan"]);
                chkthiruvanthapuram.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["trivandram"]);
                chktuticorin.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["tutucorin"]);
                chkvisakhapatanam.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["vishkapattinam"]);
                chkconsolidation.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["consolidation"]);
                chkCHA.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["CHBA"]);
                cnkFF.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["FF"]);
                chkhandling.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["handlingliveani"]);
                chkPE.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["handlingPA"]);
                chkIATA.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IATAagents"]);
                chkerecplant.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["erectionofplant"]);
                chktransp.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["liquidtrans"]);
                chkMTO.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["MTOagents"]);
                chkODC.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["ODCtran"]);
                chkImport.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["projimport"]);
                chkhandequip.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["supplycranes"]);
                chkbulkcargo.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bulkcargo"]);
                chkcargo.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["containercargo"]);
                chkware.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["warehousing"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

    }
    protected void btnconfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string companyname = txtcompanyname.Text;
        string typeofcompany = ddtypeofcmpy.SelectedValue;
        string authorizedperson = txtauthname.Text;
        string authorizedperdesig = txtauthdesg.Text;
        string registeredoffaddress = txtregoffice.Text;
        string correspondanceaddress = txtcorroffice.Text;
        string landline1 = txtll1.Text;
        string landline2 = txtll2.Text;
        string mobile1 = txtmob1.Text;
        string mobile2 = txtmob2.Text;
        string fax = txtfax.Text;
        string email = txtemail.Text;
        string website = txtweb.Text;
        string username = txtusername.Text;

        string empwithcp = txtnumempcp.Text;
        string empwocp = txtnonumempcp.Text;
        string oldCHAno = txtoldcha1.Text + "" + txtoldcha2.Text;
        string newCHAPAN = txtchnpan.Text;
        string newCHAlicence = txtchalicence.Text;
        string CHPTregnumber = txtchptreg.Text;
        string CHPTvalidity = txtchptvalid.Text;
        string aurangabad = chkaurangabad.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string bangalore = chkbangalore.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string chennai = chkchn.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string cochin = chklcochin.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string delhi = chkdelhi.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string goa = chkgoa.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string hyderabad = chkhyd.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string indore = chkindore.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string kakinada = chkkakinada.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string kandla = chkkandla.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string kolkatta = chkkolkotta.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string ludhiana = chkludhiana.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string mangalore = chkmangalore.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string mumbai = chkmumbai.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string nagpur = chknagpur.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string nashik = chknashik.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string patna = chkpatna.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string pune = chkpune.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string rajasthan = chkrajasthan.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string trivandram = chkrajasthan.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string tutucorin = chktuticorin.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string vishkapattinam = chkvisakhapatanam.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string consolidation = chkconsolidation.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string CHBA = chkCHA.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string FF = cnkFF.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string handlingliveani = chkhandling.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string handlingPA = chkPE.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string IATAagents = chkIATA.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string erectionofplant = chkerecplant.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string liquidtrans = chktransp.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string MTOagents = chkMTO.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string ODCtran = chkODC.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string projimport = chkImport.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string supplycranes = chkhandequip.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string bulkcargo = chkbulkcargo.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string containercargo = chkcargo.Checked ? "1" : "0";
        string warehousing = chkware.Checked ? "1" : "0";

        using (SqlConnection conupdate = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string queryupdate = "update insertuser set typeofcompany=@typeofcompany,authorizedperson=@authorizedperson,authorizedperdesig=@authorizedperdesig,registeredoffaddress=@registeredoffaddress,correspondanceaddress=@correspondanceaddress,landline1=@landline1,landline2=@landline2,mobile1=@mobile1,mobile2=@mobile2,fax=@fax,email=@email,website=@website,username=@username,empwithcp=@empwithcp,empwocp=@empwocp,oldCHAno=@oldCHAno,newCHAPAN=@newCHAPAN,newCHAlicence=@newCHAlicence,CHPTregnumber=@CHPTregnumber,CHPTvalidity=@CHPTvalidity,aurangabad=@aurangabad,bangalore=@bangalore,chennai=@chennai,cochin=@cochin,delhi=@delhi,goa=@goa,hyderabad=@hyderabad,indore=@indore,kakinada=@kakinada,kandla=@kandla,kolkatta=@kolkatta,ludhiana=@ludhiana,mangalore=@mangalore,bombay=@bombay,nagpur=@nagpur,nashik=@nashik,patna=@patna,pune=@pune,rajasthan=@rajasthan,trivandram=@trivandram,tutucorin=@tutucorin,vishkapattinam=@vishkapattinam,consolidation=@consolidation,CHBA=@CHBA,FF=@FF,handlingliveani=@handlingliveani,handlingPA=@handlingPA,IATAagents=@IATAagents,erectionofplant=@erectionofplant,liquidtrans=@liquidtrans,MTOagents=@MTOagents,ODCtran=@ODCtran,projimport=@projimport,supplycranes=@supplycranes,bulkcargo=@bulkcargo,containercargo=@containercargo,warehousing=@warehousing where companyname='David'";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryupdate, conupdate))
            {

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@typeofcompany", typeofcompany);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorizedperson", authorizedperson);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@authorizedperdesig", authorizedperdesig);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@registeredoffaddress", registeredoffaddress);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@correspondanceaddress", correspondanceaddress);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@landline1", landline1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@landline2", landline2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile1", mobile1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile2", mobile2);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fax", fax);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@website", website);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empwithcp", empwithcp);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empwocp", empwocp);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldCHAno", oldCHAno);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newCHAPAN", newCHAPAN);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newCHAlicence", newCHAlicence);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHPTregnumber", CHPTregnumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHPTvalidity", CHPTvalidity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aurangabad", Convert.ToInt32(aurangabad));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bangalore", Convert.ToInt32(bangalore));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chennai", Convert.ToInt32(chennai));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cochin", Convert.ToInt32(cochin));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delhi", Convert.ToInt32(delhi));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@goa", Convert.ToInt32(goa));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hyderabad", Convert.ToInt32(hyderabad));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@indore", Convert.ToInt32(indore));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kakinada", Convert.ToInt32(kakinada));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kandla", Convert.ToInt32(kandla));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kolkatta", Convert.ToInt32(kolkatta));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ludhiana", Convert.ToInt32(ludhiana));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mangalore", Convert.ToInt32(mangalore));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bombay", Convert.ToInt32(mumbai));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nagpur", Convert.ToInt32(nagpur));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nashik", Convert.ToInt32(nashik));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patna", Convert.ToInt32(patna));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pune", Convert.ToInt32(pune));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rajasthan", Convert.ToInt32(rajasthan));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trivandram", Convert.ToInt32(trivandram));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutucorin", Convert.ToInt32(tutucorin));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vishkapattinam", Convert.ToInt32(vishkapattinam));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@consolidation", Convert.ToInt32(consolidation));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHBA", Convert.ToInt32(CHBA));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FF", Convert.ToInt32(FF));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@handlingliveani", Convert.ToInt32(handlingliveani));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@handlingPA", Convert.ToInt32(handlingPA));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IATAagents", Convert.ToInt32(IATAagents));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@erectionofplant", Convert.ToInt32(erectionofplant));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@liquidtrans", Convert.ToInt32(liquidtrans));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MTOagents", Convert.ToInt32(MTOagents));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ODCtran", Convert.ToInt32(ODCtran));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@projimport", Convert.ToInt32(projimport));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@supplycranes", Convert.ToInt32(supplycranes));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bulkcargo", Convert.ToInt32(bulkcargo));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@containercargo", Convert.ToInt32(containercargo));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@warehousing", Convert.ToInt32(warehousing));
                cmd.Connection = conupdate;
                conupdate.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conupdate.Close();
            }
        }

    }
```

}
}

Comment: Any error message or exception?

Comment: Kindly Help With tyh Ifpostback options

Comment: first select companyname='Prhemnath' second where companyname='David'

Comment: no the page is loading with the old data , when i remove the page load code and update the data, it is updating in the database..

Comment: maybe because you are filling user data on every postback, check if the page_load event is fired before the btnconfirm_click event

Comment: Mr.LIUFA, No sir i tested if i load the data with different companyname still its not updating

Comment: Mr.ALi Baghdadi - Am a newbie.. how to check that can u give me an example?

Comment: I recommend you to learn how to debug your code, the solution is to put all your code of your page load event inside IsPostBack, then the data are filled only on the first load of the page, since on every time you click the button, it will fire the page_load event and fill the old data, check the answers below

Comment: Ali Baghdadi.. Thanks sir, will learn.thanks for your kind advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write the page load code inside

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{

}
```

block.

It will work.
 
You code of `page_load` should look like this

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        string strquery = "select * from insertuser Where companyname='Prhemnath'";
        SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand();
        cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdd.CommandText = strquery;
        cmdd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                txtcompanyname.Text = sdr["companyname"].ToString();
                ddtypeofcmpy.SelectedValue = sdr["typeofcompany"].ToString();
                txtauthname.Text = sdr["authorizedperson"].ToString();
                txtauthdesg.Text = sdr["authorizedperdesig"].ToString();
                txtregoffice.Text = sdr["registeredoffaddress"].ToString();
                txtcorroffice.Text = sdr["correspondanceaddress"].ToString();
                txtll1.Text = sdr["landline1"].ToString();
                txtll2.Text = sdr["landline2"].ToString();
                txtmob1.Text = sdr["mobile1"].ToString();
                txtmob2.Text = sdr["mobile2"].ToString();
                txtfax.Text = sdr["email"].ToString();
                txtemail.Text = sdr["email"].ToString();
                txtweb.Text = sdr["website"].ToString();
                txtusername.Text = sdr["username"].ToString();
                txtnumempcp.Text = sdr["empwithcp"].ToString();
                txtnonumempcp.Text = sdr["empwocp"].ToString();
                txtchnpan.Text = sdr["newCHAPAN"].ToString();
                txtchalicence.Text = sdr["newCHAlicence"].ToString();
                txtchptreg.Text = sdr["CHPTregnumber"].ToString();
                txtchptvalid.Text = sdr["CHPTvalidity"].ToString();
                chkaurangabad.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["aurangabad"]);
                chkbangalore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bangalore"]);
                chkchn.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["chennai"]);
                chklcochin.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["cochin"]);
                chkdelhi.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["delhi"]);
                chkgoa.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["goa"]);
                chkhyd.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["hyderabad"]);
                chkindore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["kakinada"]);
                chkkandla.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["kolkatta"]);
                chkludhiana.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["ludhiana"]);
                chkmangalore.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["mangalore"]);
                chkmumbai.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bombay"]);
                chknagpur.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["nagpur"]);
                chknashik.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["nashik"]);
                chkpatna.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["patna"]);
                chkpune.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["pune"]);
                chkrajasthan.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["rajasthan"]);
                chkthiruvanthapuram.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["trivandram"]);
                chktuticorin.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["tutucorin"]);
                chkvisakhapatanam.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["vishkapattinam"]);
                chkconsolidation.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["consolidation"]);
                chkCHA.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["CHBA"]);
                cnkFF.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["FF"]);
                chkhandling.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["handlingliveani"]);
                chkPE.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["handlingPA"]);
                chkIATA.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["IATAagents"]);
                chkerecplant.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["erectionofplant"]);
                chktransp.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["liquidtrans"]);
                chkMTO.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["MTOagents"]);
                chkODC.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["ODCtran"]);
                chkImport.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["projimport"]);
                chkhandequip.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["supplycranes"]);
                chkbulkcargo.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["bulkcargo"]);
                chkcargo.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["containercargo"]);
                chkware.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["warehousing"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
        }
```

Comment: Will try and let you know sir, Thanks in advance